# Different Results with client.svc and search api

Tags: 2013, search, csom

I made a search which is only searching on a specific list. The list has 30132 elements.

- client.svc with the seach Webpart
- _api/search/ with a specfic form

Both searches are returning a different number of totalRows when I search for "*"(`client.svc returns 30132` and `_api/search returns 29858`).

Any idea why and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

URL for the Ajax request:

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='<searchTerm> AND ListId:<idOfTheList>'&rowlimit=100&trimduplicates=false
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be the TrimDuplicates functionality!

Try adding `&trimduplicates=false` to the end of your `_api/search` string.

This functionality is meant to eliminate "duplicate" results, like documents with exactyl the same names and content.

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx (search for TrimDuplicates)

Comment: didnt't work, i get 30157 elements with trimduplicates=false

Comment: Well closer ;) I guess EnablePhonetics and EnableNicknames and other properties like that can count..

Comment: I tried both parameters but nothing changed

Comment: Did you specify a result source? @RobertLindgren approach is correct, there is something missing (or added) that is causing the query to be different.

Comment: added the URL for the Ajax request in my question